# Binary operations with macros in C++

Tags: c++, macros, binary

I would like to use binary flags through macros, but getting compiler error on following:

```
#define FLAG_A 0x01;
#define FLAG_B 0x02;

int binVal = 0;
binVal = FLAG_A | FLAG_B;

//getting 0x03 here
```

but compiler ends with:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘|’ token
```

Tried:

```
binVal = 0x01 | 0x02; //this does perfectly well.
```

Thanks for your response in advance.

Comment: Hence, don't ever use macros like this. It would have worked fine if you had used an enumeration or constexpr int.

Answer (score 8):

Remove the semi-colons:

```
#define FLAG_A 0x01
#define FLAG_B 0x02
```

Otherwise the statement will be expanded to

```
binVal = 0x01; | 0x02;;
```

Answer (score 4):

That's why you **never, ever** want to put semicolons after your macro definitions. They're not needed for the preprocessor; if they're there they'll be incorporated into the expanded macro, giving a syntax error. Use

```
#define FLAG_A 0x01
#define FLAG_B 0x02
```

instead. If you want those semicolons, you can also use an enumeration:

```
enum flag {
    FLAG_A = 0x1,
    FLAG_B = 0x2
};
```

Comment: Thanks did it hundred times before, with no semicolons, bit tired today. Thanks again.